# Is it possibile to set ng-show by using jQuert attr element in Angular?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to change the ng-show attribute of an element.
But it seems that Angular ignore it.
Why?

```
element.attr('ng-show',false)
```

I tried to do scope.$apply, buy still angular ignore this attribute.

Is it possible to change ng-show attribute after the run-time?

Comment: completely wrong approach....change the scope model. You will need to use `$compile` if you **must** do what you are doing. This seems to be a trend that you keep trying to do things yourself in the DOM and not using angular the way it should be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as it is [explained here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2271482&seqNum=3), after the Compilation phase for AngularJS any other directive that you insert in the HTML will be unreachable.
That is because, Angular transverse the whole DOM only once in order to improve performance.

btw, why are you doing that? Instead I will prefer an attribute from a controller to listen directly on that particular element of your html.

Answer (score 1):

ng-show should be assigned the value from the scope that resolves to a boolean.  Changing that boolean scope variable to true or false should hide or show the element.